# Finding the Body Volume between two functions: $x^2+y^2+z^2=20$ and $z=x^2+y^2$ ( triangle intergral )

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, volume

usually I manage to solve those questions, but this one in particular is problematic, I have no other information.
If I try to use $z=x^2+y^2$ in the Ball function, I will get $(x+y)^2+x^4+y^4=20$, which is not a really possible way to solve it...
I tried geogebra, saw the shape it was a flat ball ( I dont know why... ).
Can anyone give me any tip on how to start? I dont know what I need to put at the boundary of the Third integral...
I dont have any radius.
The only think I thought of doing: using polar coordinates: $x^2+y^2=\rho^2$, thus I am getting after a few calculations: $\rho_1=\sqrt(10)$, $\rho_2=-\sqrt(10)$
So I can probably use $\rho=0$ to $\rho=\sqrt10$.
$\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$ ( just guessing, because it has a circle shape from $x^2+y^2$ ).
but the last angle I dont know what to do...
Can somone tell me if my direction is correct \ What can I do to solve it?
My problem here is the $x^4$ and $y^4$

The answer is:$\frac 83\pi(10\sqrt5-19)$

According to help I got (my try):
Okay, I got something close: $\frac {16}3\pi(10\sqrt5-16)$.
This time $\rho$ is between $0$ to $2$.
$\theta$ is between $0$ to $2\pi$
$z$ is between $\sqrt{20-\rho^2})$ with minus and plus

Comment: You also get $z + z^2=20$

Comment: @Peter yea, but how does that help me? I thought of it to be honest. at the end I just went on and did something else.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot... I understand, I can find the radius now and thus solve it pretty easy.. Ow....

Comment: Peter Hi, sorry for the intrusion again.
Regarding the question, I got somehow zero, what is my mistake? I got to polar coordinates, Z=5, $\rho=\sqrt5$ with plus and minus.
My integral boundarys were: $\theta$ is between 0 to $2\pi$, $\rho$ is  between Minus and plus $\sqrt5$ and z is  between Plus and minus $\sqrt{20-\rho^2}$

EDit: tried also when $\rho$ is between $0$ to $5$, I get minus thingy, and not close to the answer sadly... where is my mistake?

Comment: Equation gives z=-5, z=4, but z<0 is not allowed, so z from 0 to 4. Each "slice" is an annulus, and you can calculate inner and outer radii as functions of z.

Comment: Ohhhh, I didnt notice that in the a,b,c in the quadratic equation, I did -1 instead of +1... I am really not focused.. thank you so much , I think I got it from here on now.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much!!  I think I solved it, I got something close, but not exactly it...
This time I did $\rho$ from $0$ to $2$, I got: $\frac {16}3\pi(10\sqrt5-16)$
could it be their answers are wrong? they had some wrong answers sometimes to be honest.
I would have uploaded what I did, but writing in latex is really hard for me.. it took me 1.5 page to do the intergral part ( I am sure it is correct )

Comment: @Peter Hi peter, can you try to explain to me why is the lower bound need to be $\rho^2$ and not like I did? I am having hard time understanding it :(

Answer (score 1):

The region is axisymmetric about the $z$ axis. It you make $x=0$ and draw the intersection with the $zy$-plane you'll see very clearly what the integration limits should be. In cylindrical coordinates you would have:
\begin{align*}
V = &\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_{\rho^2}^{\sqrt{20-\rho^2}} \rho \,dz\, d\rho\, d\theta\\
=& 2 \pi \int_0^2 \rho(\sqrt{20-\rho^2}-\rho^2)d\rho = \cdots =\frac{8}{3} \left(10 \sqrt{5}-19\right) \pi
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I did the integral almost as close as you did at the last part, execept I did by both the boundarys of the intergral $\sqrt{(20-\rho^2)}$.
Can you please explain to me why I dont do both boundarys like that?

Comment: At my last try I got this: $\frac {16}3\pi(10\sqrt5-16)$. Could it be the correct answer?

Comment: @lirongozal The spherical surface only bounds the region from above. See the picture I added to my answer.

Comment: Plugging the integral I posted into mathematica, the result is $\frac{1}{6} \left(-3+160 \sqrt{5}-76 \sqrt{19}\right) \pi$.

Comment: What. It doesnt seem usual, are you sure? why is it like that? its weird we will get an answer like that... I have to make sure somehow, its really weird, none of our answers were as complicated as that... with having to calculate such stuff.
Ahh I dont know what to say...

Comment: @lirongozal I made a mistake with thr $\rho$ limits in mathematica. the correct answer is $\frac{8}{3} \left(10 \sqrt{5}-19\right) \pi$.

Comment: Oh, but why is it like that? how? the radius is 2, not one.. I am really having trouble understanding this,...
I got something else, and I dont know what is the reason... I did boundaries like you, but only the lower bound of z was different between us...

Comment: @lirongozal you need to actually do the calculations... Did you compute the antiderivative correctly?

Comment: I did it on my notebook.
I already said what i got.
I did the same boundaries as you, but lower bound of z of mine was the same as the higher bound but with minus. but you did only $\rho^2$ - that is the reason for our difference, but I dont know why you did it like that....

Comment: @lirongozal Did you take a look at the picture I posted? The curve that limits the set from below is $z = x^2+y^2$, which in cylindrical coordinates is $z = \rho^2$.

Comment: I did, I know, I saw it. but as I said, I didnt understand why...  that is the issue here, not the integrals, why is it like that, thats my problem to understand it...

Comment: Why the lower boundry of Z is equal to $\rho^2$ and not like higher bound with minus but... I did the same as you, but with lower bound like high, but with minus... I need to understand it.

Comment: I didnt understand why Z is positive always... I saw what you did in the picture, but why is it positive?

Comment: Ohhh, I think I understand now, because z as in z and as in z^2, is always positive.
X^2 is always positive, y^2 is always positive, thus its always positive.... I see now, so thats why the lower bound is like that... in that case it should be 0 and not $\rho^2$, why is it like that and not $0$? since Z is greater and equal to 0, so the lower bound should be 0.

Comment: The set is the region between a paraboloid and a sphere, and the paraboloid is above the $xy$-axis. $z$ is positive all over  the set.

Comment: Yea I just noticed it, but since its positive, its lower bound should be 0, not $\rho^2$, it doesnt start at 10, it start at 0.

Comment: @lirongozal In my picture, if you set $y = 1$, what is the lowest possible value for $z$? (hint: not zero)

Comment: but if you set y=0, you get z=0... so it does start at z=0

Comment: @lirongozal But that just happens for $y=0$... You have a fundamental lack of understanding on the analytical description of regions of the plane and space and should ask your professor for help on this subsject.

Comment: Its really weird, since I really know how to answer those questions, I understand them, I draw them on paper and I understand what I do. but I really cant understand why Z=0 has to be always in order to be lower bound...
the bound of z has to be some sort of function, the question is, what function gets me the $\rho^2$, thats my main issue understanding...
Thanks for the trying though... my professor wont be able to help me with it, thanks anyway :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133922/discussion-between-pierrecarre-and-liron-gozal).

Answer (score 1):

We know that the solid is bounded by the surfaces $z=x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=20$. The first of these conditions also implies that $z\ge0$, and this condition together with the second boundary surface defines a hemisphere.

Substituting the two equations gives $z^2+z-20=0$, leading to $z=4$ where the two surfaces meet.

We now calculate the section of the hemisphere *outside* the solid.

For each $z\space \epsilon \space [0,4]$ we have an annulus of inner radius $r_1 =\sqrt{z}$ and outer radius $r_2=\sqrt{20 - z^2}$.

The area of the annulus is $A=\pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)=\pi(20-z^2-z)$.

Integrating this area over the range
$z\space \epsilon \space [0,4]$ gives $$\int_0^4\pi(20-z^2-z)dz=\frac{\pi\cdot152}{3}$$
The volume of the hemisphere is $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{4\pi}{3}20\sqrt{20}=\frac{80\pi}{3}\sqrt{5}$$
Subtracting these gives $\frac{8\pi}{3}(10\sqrt{5}-19)$ as required.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not need the whole answer, my problem is understanding, why is the inner radius $z$ and not $\sqrt{20-z^2}$? that is my problem. The whole question I know how to answer, but my answer is wrong only because of the lower boundry of that sqrt, I need to understand that and thats it :(

Comment: Ohh I understood now, I didnt notice Z is equal to z^2... that is my mistake, I am an idiot.. thanks!